# Sonar issue: define a constant instead of duplicating this literal

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am having the below log line in a java file 3 times in my project==

```
   log.info(
                    "Queuing workflow message with ID {} and shardedDatabaseId {}",
                    workflowQueueMessageString,
                    shardedDatabaseId);
```

This is generating a critical issue by sonar==

Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal "Queuing workflow message with ID {} and shardId {}" 3 times.

I can understand the reason for this error. But the string is actually not a constant and has placeholders like {}. So how to correctly address this Sonar reported issue.

Comment: Alternative: perhaps you could add a bit more context (i.e. use a different message) in the different locations?

Comment: But the string _literal_ itself is constant and repeated. Your argument is similar to saying "3600" is not constant, because I'm using it in calculations – `var two_hours = 2 * 3600; var one_day = 24 * 3600;`

Comment: "the string is actually not a constant" -- how is it not a constant? Every String literal is a constant. And is that issue really marked as "critical"?? I would ignore it (or mark to be ignored) IMHO there is nothing critical with using a literal m*essage* directly, in logging or similar, actually easier to read and even to avoid errors like changing the message and overseeing it is being used somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is the *format* of the log message. Even if the message itself is not constant, the format **is** constant.

Just declare it (the format) as a variable - final, static, whatever is applicable to the use case.

```
String messageFormat = "Queuing workflow message with ID {} and shardedDatabaseId {}";
log.info(messageFormat, workflowQueueMessageString, shardedDatabaseId);
...
log.info(messageFormat, workflowQueueMessageString, shardedDatabaseId);
...
log.info(messageFormat, workflowQueueMessageString, shardedDatabaseId);
```

Comment: thanks, didnot know that their was such a simple solution -:)